# A parameter should have all the methods, and be similar to, a Multiprocessing Connect, is it correct to say "should obey the semantics of"

Tags: semantics

I have a function that takes an object which should implement all the methods of a multiprocessing connection:

"""
ctx_pipe should obey the semantics of a multiprocessing Connection object
"""

If not, what does "obey the semantics" mean? In which context could it be used? What alterntives are there?

Note: Although this is a question related to English, I thought it fit better on stackoverflow.